# Grouping mysql by a regex?

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying to find the count of how many times a location is used in my table of search results, but I want to group together cases where the same post code area start is used. The following groups purely on the text used:

```
SELECT count(*), 
    search_browse_log.postcode_start 
FROM search_browse_log 
GROUP BY postcode_start 
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

But in the data, I have for example CR0, CR1, CR2 (postcode starts). I want to group them all together so I have a count of 3 for "CR", rather than 1 each of CR0, CR1 and CR2.

Thanks in advance if you can help!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a conditional in the `GROUP BY` clause to get either 1 or 2 characters, depending on whether the postcode starts with 1 or 2 letters.

```
GROUP BY IF(postcode_start REGEXP '^[A-Z][A-Z]', 
                LEFT(postcode_start, 2), 
                LEFT(postcode_start, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's only the first 2 characters of the postcode, you could use the LEFT function in the group by:

```
SELECT count(*), 
    LEFT(postcode_start,2) as `postcode_start`
FROM search_browse_log 
GROUP BY LEFT(postcode_start,2)
ORDER BY count() DESC
```

To group by the non-numeric characters at the start of the string:

```
SELECT count(*), 
    IF(postcode_start REGEX '^[a-ZA-Z][0-9]',LEFT(postcode_start,1),LEFT(postcode_start,2)) as `postcode_start`
FROM search_browse_log 
GROUP BY IF(postcode_start REGEX '^[a-ZA-Z][0-9]',LEFT(postcode_start,1),LEFT(postcode_start,2))
ORDER BY count() DESC
```

For reference, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

Comment: Thanks, but there could just be 1 letter at the start. Either 1 or 2

Comment: Do you want to group by all non-numeric characters at the start of the string?

Comment: That's the postcode format here in the UK. It could be CR0 1AA or E3 2PN, in this column I'm storing the first part of that, ie CR0 or E3. But I want to group to find how many of e.g. CR* or E* there are.

Comment: "group by all non-numeric characters at the start of the string" yes that should do it

Comment: Thanks, I had tried that but I'm getting syntax errors by the regex

Comment: `postcode_start REGEXP '^[a-ZA-Z]*'` returns a boolean, not the part of the string that matches the regexp.

Comment: @Newmania Edit the question to clarify how you're trying to group it. There's nothing in the question that says that it could be one or two letters.

Comment: There are some syntax errors here. `REGEX` should be `REGEXP`, and `COUNT()` should be `COUNT(*)`

Comment: Oops! You're right! Fixed in answer. But, you're right in your previous comment. I'll look and see if there's a way to return the first non-numeric characters....

Comment: Since it's a limited case with 1 or 2 characters at the start of the string, the updated answer above should work.